# I get the CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_array() in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I get the CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_array() error when trying to display a cell value.

This is my model

```
function list_get($id){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db-> select('*')
        ->from('lists')
        ->join('list_items', 'list_items.items_list_id = lists.list_id')
        ->where('items_list_id', $id);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

The error appears when I try to `echo` it to the view `<?echo $query['list_by'];?>`

Comment: The controller and possibly the view code will need to be shared.

Comment: Hey @DFriend this is the controller. 
`public function view_list($id = !FALSE){
        $this->load->model('model_lists');
        $data["query"] = $this->model_lists->list_get($id);
        $this->load->model('model_lists');
        if($data["query"]){

            $this->load->view('lists/view_list',$data);
        } else {
            redirect('lists');
        }
    }` 
And the view is `<?echo $query['list_by'];?>`